# How can code opened in a container execute arbitrary code outside the container?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I generally work inside of docker containers both to keep my local environment clean, and to sandbox.  However, when I use VSCode Remote Containers to try to open a folder in a container I am told:

> Opening a folder in a Dev Container may execute arbitrary code both inside and outside the container.

[image]

The docs link, unfortunately, only talks about Workspace Trust in general and don't mention anything about the risks around containers.

**What are the specific risks that I'm taking on by clicking "Trust Folder & Continue" when working inside a dev container?**  What attack vectors am I opening myself up to by clicking Trust here?  Is there anything I can do within VSCode to mitigate the risks beyond working inside of a container (e.g., can I disable some specific feature(s))?

Comment: Maybe if one mounts host OS folders into the Dev Container this could open for attack? Found [this page with potentially some more information](https://dev.to/jamiemccrindle/exploiting-visual-studio-code-devcontainers-16fb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This made me very curious what may go wrong, and I have found some ways to get outside without user interaction

### 1. Abuse `tasks.json`

I thing it very cool feature may because of `"runOn": "folderOpen"` can lead to arbitrary code execution on the host, take a look on this example

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "start browser",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:\\Progra~1\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com",
                "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            },
            "dependsOn": ["back"]
        },
        {
            "label": "back",
            "command": "${command:remote-containers.reopenLocally}"
        }
    ]
}
```

You may feel running tasks inside container is safe, BUT this one doing 2 things

- on open without user interaction trying to go back to local machine
- then open browser and opens [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)

If just had to trust this folder then tasks with option `"runOn": "folderOpen"` will be triggered without your interaction

Another thing is that as your host Directory and one inside docker are always synchronized it may modify own files (including `tasks.json`) then try to execute it

### 2. Abuse `features/docker-outside-of-docker`

If you are running dev container you may be started with additional features, one of them is called `docker-outside-of-docker`

```json
    "features": {
        "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/docker-outside-of-docker:1": {}
    }
```

If Dev Container is completely remote machine maybe your host won't be touched but machine where docker is running may be damaged

Then we can create task like

```json
        {
            "label": "list host",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "docker run --rm -v /:/host alpine whoami && cat /etc/passwd"
        }
```

And execute anything on the host as `root`!

---

If we go to [the documentation link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust) that you talked about we can find there

> Restricted Mode tries to prevent automatic code execution by disabling or limiting the operation of several VS Code features: tasks, debugging, workspace settings, and extensions.

You can clearly see that `tasks` are disabled along with other VS Code features that can probably lead to arbitrary code execution.

I didn't try but looking how [`launch.json` looks like](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_showdisplaystring) you can also see that any shell code can be executed, so even without `tasks` but with Docker host access can damage it, and even without this container has an access your local network and try attack your Router, Printer or other PC if they have some port open, I know it's becoming long chain but possible, take a look at [Operation Triangulation: The last (hardware) mystery](https://securelist.com/operation-triangulation-the-last-hardware-mystery/111669/) especially this image
[image: (https://media.kasperskycontenthub.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/43/2023/12/25130925/trng_final_mystery_en_01.png) how long it can be]

So as `devcontainer.json`, `tasks.json` and `launch.json` are inside workspace and contain executable code they have to be trusted

Comment: Great to see some practical examples for the hypothetical reasoning in the documentation why they are disabling build automation tasks etc.

Comment: Yes, I haven't seen real attack using it, but as often developers have too much confidence in what they trust we are becoming easy target. Almost the same apply to CI server it's "just CI" but they contain many credentials(it a little out of scope for this question, I know)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for!  It is unfortunate that they felt the solution was to completely disable everything, rather than just plugging what seems like extreme security holes such as the ability to tell VSCode to restart outside of the container.

Comment: I think `solution was to completely disable everything` is not true as you have a button to enable it. Security is always a cost in this case the cost is time clicking button every time you open possibly malicious directory. You never know what other way people will find to escape sandbox

Answer (score 2):

The warning and the concept of trusted folders *is*  what VSCode does to mitigate the risk of arbitrary code execution.

The risk precisely lies in that VSCode is running outside of the container on your machine, and it has the ability to run code.

Usually the attack vector would be build automation tasks, which are handled by tooling frameworks. And since build frameworks by definition have the power of writing to disk and execution of binaries.

Depending on the setup, it might be enough for you to open a container that has a task configuration to run certain tools upon opening, infecting the system by merely opening the project folder in VSCode with automation enabled.

To close this vector, VSCode usually will not trust the files and folders that you open, and in those scenarios it disables functions and extensions that may act as the motor behind an attack.

You can read more about the decision and thoughts behind the concept of workspace trust in [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust).

Comment: I believe everything you have described applies only to running outside of a container.  Running inside of a container should mitigate all of those risks, which is why I am trying to understand what risks remain that VSCode is trying to protect me from.  Also, I believe the article you linked is the same one linked in the screenshot I shared, which only talks about outside of a container.

Comment: But even when you use dev containers, the VS Code instance is running outside of the container, right? Inside the container is "just" the server, and the project itself is also only mounted into the container but still existing on your actual host drive. I admit I'm not quite familiar with dev containers yet, but from what I understand all it would take is for an attacker to delete the `.devcontainer` file and restart VSC to bypass the dev container extension starting the protective layer?

Comment: Is a script running inside the container capable restarting the VSCode?  This certainly feels like a security vulnerability, but one that should be filed as such and fixed.  Do you have any references on how a script running inside a VS Code instance can trigger a restart of VS Code?

Comment: I currently wouldn't know of any references where it has been done. But I haven't used every extension there is, either. Maybe it's even simpler and they try to protect against a yet-to-be-found exploit in the dev container extension itself.